# 2nd degree inter-Relationships between nodes Using cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a question, I am trying to solve the query , i created this query and i got the results, but i am not sure if it is correct or not. Please have a look and if something is not correct please let me know. The idea is simple. When starting from one node N , A and B calls N, i want to see in 2nd degree where only a calls b and b calls A. Results are in count and collections. please have a look at the below mentioned query.(Inter-Relationships are the 'q')

```
START n=node(12742)
MATCH p=(a)-[:CALLS]-(n)-[:CALLS]-(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH q=(a)-[:CALLS*0..2]->(b),(b)-[:CALLS*0..2]->(a) 
RETURN
  DISTINCT a.num ,
  COUNT(DISTINCT b.num) AS Total_B_numbers,
  Collect(b.num) AS bSideNumber,
  count(DISTINCT q) AS Com_Rel,
  count(DISTINCT p) AS Normal_Rel
ORDER BY Com_Rel;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What sort of error / problem are you having?  I have a few bits of feedback:

I think you might want to try the variable length path starting at a length of `1`.  A length of `0` means that it can refer to itself.  This would be:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH q=(a)-[:CALLS*1..2]->(b),(b)-[:CALLS*1..2]->(a)
```

Also, this wouldn't be your issue, but you should get into the habit of not using `START` as that syntax will eventually be removed from Neo4j.  That would make your first two lines:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[:CALLS]-(n)-[:CALLS]-(b)
WHERE ID(n) = 12742
```

Also be careful about using internal Neo4j IDs as long term identifiers (not saying that's what you're doing here, but in future versions IDs of nodes may get shuffled around for performance)

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried the `WHERE` clause instead of `START` . But the results with  `WHERE ID(n)` clause the results are totally different. There are no collections for the bNumbers. If i use the `START` then i have the results. Is there something i need to change in the query? One more thing in the row view of neo4j i got the individual results for `Com_Rel` i tried to use the `WITH SUM()` to collect the total numbers of `Com_Rel` but found nothing. Any suggestion on that. Once again thanks

Comment: You might play around with returning just parts of your `RETURN` clause.  Specifically you might try removing/changing the `DISTINCT a.num` as that's the only non-aggregating column.  Also, you might just try one aggregation at a time to see what you get.

Comment: That seems really strange about the `START` vs `WHERE`.  I would double check that you're using the right ID, etc...  Also, you could try starting with `MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = 12742 WITH n` instead of `START`

Comment: Yes, i tried this one as well, 
`MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = 12742 WITH n`
 Results are the same as the 
`MATCH p=(a)-[:CALLS]-(n)-[:CALLS]-(b)
WHERE ID(n) = 12742`
instead of 
`START n=node(12742)` this is bit strange. in general i don't see any difference between these two queries. is there?